# Drupal 7 Unable to clear view cache in custom module

Tags: drupal-7

I have a view and it is responding fine for the filters I give. However when I run this multiple times in a for loop in my module, I get the same response for whichever filter I apply.

I searched the web and found code to turn off view caching. I have also disabled views data caching from structure->views->settings->advanced. But that is not working.

Below is the example code:

```
foreach ($term_ids as $term_id) {

    $view2 = test_generate_view($view_name, $display_handler, $page, $count, $term_id);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($view2);

}

function test_generate_view($view_name, $display_handler, $page, $count, $term_id = null) {

    $view = views_get_view($view_name, TRUE);

    $view->set_display($display_handler);

    if (!empty($term_id)) {
        $term_item                   = $view->get_item($display_handler, 'filter', 'field_ref_issue_target_id');
        $term_item['value']['value'] = $term_id;

        $view->set_item($display_handler, 'filter', 'field_ref_issue_target_id', $term_item);

    }

    $view->init_pager();
    $view->pager['items_per_page']               = $count;
    $view->pager['use_pager']                    = true;
    $view->display_handler->options['use_pager'] = true;
    $view->set_items_per_page($count);
    $view->pager['current_page'] = $page;

    $view->is_cacheable = FALSE;

    $view->pre_execute();
    $view->execute();

    return $view;
}
```

If I don't run them in a loop and try separately for every term-id its working fine. But if I run them in a loop like above, the output is same for any term-id.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't look so bad and because the filter changes, the caching should deliver a different result even if turned on. Because the code is working without the loop, maybe you should look into that. is $term_ids really an array of integer values or an array of term objects? If so, the function call would fall back to default which is null for term_ids and would not add a filter.

By the way: You should have a look at contextual filters which you can use really easily.